# How can I save a web page in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

Using `Ruby` and `Watir`, can I save a web page the same way as doing a right `mouse-click` and " `save page with name` "?

I need to save the current web page from a script.

Comment: Do you need to save the entire web page (ie external CSS, scripts, images, etc) or just the HTML? As well, are there frames on the page?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it with `watir`. Just open a page and save the `browser.html` to any destination you want:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs    # I am using phantomjs for scripted browsing
b.goto 'http://google.com'
File.open('/tmp/google', 'w') {|f| f.write b.html }
```

Comment: Thank you , it's working pretty well :)
If I can ask more, it's possible to save a file with dynamic name?
For example, making a for cycle ( between 0 and 5 ) could I save
/tmp/google0 , /tmp/google1 and so on?

Comment: Something like (assuming `i=0` at the beginning): `filename = "/tmp/google#{i = (i + 1) % 6}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about watir, but I know the way to do it using Selenium Web Driver is using the page source method.
Check out the docs for that here:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html#page_source-instance_method

using this, you should get the whole source.

You can now save the source, by just creating a new file. I haven't tried this but you can check it out.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
driver.get(URL_of_page_to_save)
file = File.new(filename, "w")
file.puts(driver.page_source)
file.close
```

Not sure if this saves all elements of the page.

Hope this helped a bit!